# Google Jobs: Quota exceeded for the number of App Engine Cron jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, scheduled-task, google-app-engine

Yesterday at 8:00 am, I had a quota of 250 app-engine jobs.

At 9:00 am, I deployed a yaml file with 280 jobs, I got this error:

```
"error": {
"code": 429,
"message": "Quota exceeded for the number of App Engine Cron jobs.",
"status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"}
```

**=> fair enough**

At 9:40 am, I asked GCP to increase the quotas of app-engine jobs to 500.

At 4 pm, the quota was increased => very good.(I can see it in Quotas in Google Console)

Since yesterday 4pm, I tried to deploy a schedule jobs file with 150-200 jobs, and I always get:

```
"code": 429,
"message": "Quota exceeded for the number of App Engine Cron jobs.",
```

What could go wrong ? Is there a delay if I reach the limit of a quota ?

Comment: I have few questions for you :

1. How did you make the quota increase in App Engine Cron?
2. Is the problem fixed or are you still getting the error code 429 with the Quota exceeded message when deploying your cron.yaml file?

Comment: Hi @PriyashreeBhadra, sorry for the late reply. 1- I increased the quota in "Quotas" menu in IAM & Admin, now I have 1000 jobs as a limit. 2- I still get the error code 429 every time I deploy more than 250 jobs (which is the default limit).

Answer (score 0):

So I still couldn't deploy the cron.yaml file from the pipeline.

So I deploy a small cron.yaml (20 jobs) file from the local CLI. And now the jobs are deployed from the pipeline.

It looks like a bug on GCP.